# How to surpass Parse.com BeforeDelete / AfterDelete 3 second rule?

Tags: parse-platform

When I am deleting a content in the database I first delte the comment objects inside of it.

Its like this
BeforeDelete(
 Delete all of the comments in the content
 Delete other stuff about the content
).then(
 Delete Content
)

but some contents have over 200 objects which has to be deleted before deleting the content and 3 seconds is not enough for all of that processing.
In 3 seconds parse can delete around 40-45 objects.

So what can I do to extend this time?

Answer (score 0):

You can't extend the 3 second limitation on post save/delete hooks.

I've faced this problem in the past, and I'll take one of two approaches.

**DestroyAll**

Use the Parse.Object.DestroyAll method.

This is much faster than manually iterating through the list of objects to be destroyed, and destroying them one at a time. Note however, that if your sub-objects being destroyed have their own post-delete hooks, you'll likely exceed your 3 second total limit.

There is actually a parse blog post about destroyAll which could be helpful to you here: 
http://blog.parse.com/2013/08/22/deleting-objects/

I've repeated the example from their webpage here. It pretty much directly addresses your usecase of deleting multiple objects in a post-delete hook.

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeDelete("Comment", function(request, response) {
  var elapsed = 0;
  var date = request.object.get("date");

  if (date) {
    elapsed = (Date.now() - date.getTime()) / 1000;
  }

  if (elapsed &lt; 60) {
    response.success();
  } else {
    response.error("Can't delete comments more than a minute old"); 
  }
});
```

**Queue**

For the more complex cases I'll use some kind of secondary queue mechanism.

When an object is due for deletion. I'll either update a field to reflect it's pending deletion status "set("pendingDeletion",true).

Or I'll add it to some "deleteQueue", which is checked periodically.

**Jobs**

All your "child" objects can have a reference to their parent. Have a cloud job which runs at a regular interval. On every invocation check to see if a child's parent reference is invalid. If it is, the child is an orphan, and destroy the orphan.

I would try the DestroyAll method to start with, as it is far simpler than ther others. But I can expand on the other two methods with code examples if DestroyAll is timing out.